# Why did Kierkegaard disagree with Schopenhauer?

Tags: kierkegaard, schopenhauer

I read that towards the end of his short life Kierkegaard encountered Schopenhauer's philosophy. However, it seems that he did not really like Schopenhauer (I believe he just made a dismissive remark that Schopenhauer does not practice what he preaches), which I find surprising, since the two great thinkers had a lot in common, like both had a pessimistic worldview, and both disliked scholastic systematic philosophy of the Hegelian type.

What was it that made Kierkegaard dislike (disagree with) Schopenhauer and his philosophy?